# Assist with simple count out of a list

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to count the number of people marked as Break in a column in a list.

currently when I run my foreach loop (the one at the bottom) to count the number of breaks listed it throws the error message cannot convert type char to string. I understand that my class of NewAgent does not contain all string values but I'm only trying to reference one string.  I need a way to count the number of times break appears in my list. Break would appear under newAgent.auxreason

```
public List newAgentList;
List<NewAgent> newAgentList = new List<NewAgent>();

NewAgent newAgents = new ScoreBoardClientTest.NewAgent();

foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
{


    newAgents.AgentName = item.AgName;

    newAgents.AgentExtension = item.Extension;

    newAgents.AgentDateTimeChange = ConvertedDateTimeUpdated;

    newAgents.AuxReasons = item.AuxReasonDescription;

    newAgents.LoginIdentifier = item.LoginId;

    newAgents.AgentState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;

    var timeSpanSince = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;
    newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange = timeSpanSince;

    newAgentList.Add(newAgents);
}

int breakCount = 0;
foreach(string s in newAgents.AuxReasons)
{
    if (s != null && s.StartsWith("Break")) breakCount++;
}
```

Comment: You are never changing `newAgents` in your loop, you're just adding the same object over and over.  This code needs some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int breakCount = 0;
foreach(var agent in newAgentList)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(agent.AuxReasons) && agent.AuxReasons.StartsWith("Break"))
      breakCount++;
}
```

You should also create new object in each iteration:

```
foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
{
    NewAgent newAgents = new ScoreBoardClientTest.NewAgent();

    newAgents.AgentName = item.AgName;

    newAgents.AgentExtension = item.Extension;

    newAgents.AgentDateTimeChange = ConvertedDateTimeUpdated;

    newAgents.AuxReasons = item.AuxReasonDescription;

    newAgents.LoginIdentifier = item.LoginId;

    newAgents.AgentState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;

    var timeSpanSince = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;
    newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange = timeSpanSince;

    newAgentList.Add(newAgents);
}
```

Comment: This ended up resolving my issue. I marked your answer because you posted first. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to put `NewAgent newAgents = new ScoreBoardClientTest.NewAgent();` inside your first `foreach` loop because right now you are working with reference to the same object and if you update any property of this object in one place it will be updated for the entire list.

Second, you need to work with `newAgentList` in the second loop and not with `newAgents` (this is why you are seeing the exception since you are going trough chars inside the string instead of going trough elements of a list).

This should work:

```
public List newAgentList;
List<NewAgent> newAgentList = new List<NewAgent>();

foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
{
    NewAgent newAgents = new ScoreBoardClientTest.NewAgent();

    newAgents.AgentName = item.AgName;
    newAgents.AgentExtension = item.Extension;
    newAgents.AgentDateTimeChange = ConvertedDateTimeUpdated;
    newAgents.AuxReasons = item.AuxReasonDescription;
    newAgents.LoginIdentifier = item.LoginId;
    newAgents.AgentState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;

    var timeSpanSince = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;
    newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange = timeSpanSince;

    newAgentList.Add(newAgents);
}

int breakCount = 0;
foreach(string s in newAgentList.AuxReasons)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.AuxReasons) && s.AuxReasons.StartsWith("Break")) breakCount++;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and mine?

Comment: at the time I post this answer I didn't see yours - I'm new to SO, so it took me a while to properly format my answer, so sorry for that. I will update page before posting next time to be sure that nobody was ahead of me. My answer contains brief explanation of why he's facing any issues though

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, we're doing something bad in the loop.

You're declaring `newAgents`, and setting it over and over again, so it will always have values equal to the last item in `e.CmsData.Agents`. For example, if you have a list, and the `AgName`s of the items in the list are:

```
Bob
Michael
James
```

`newAgents` is always going to have an `AgentName` of "James" when the loop completes, because it's declared out of scope of the loop. Fix this by moving the declaration of your `NewAgent` placeholder inside the scope of the loop, like following:

```
List<NewAgent> newAgentList = new List<NewAgent>();
foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
{
    NewAgent newAgents = new ScoreBoardClientTest.NewAgent();
    // perform your data transforms
    newAgentList.Add(newAgents);
}
```

That will make it so you're actually adding elements to your list that correspond to the data you're trying to manipulate, and there is no need for that variable to exist outside the loop.

Are you trying to count the number of reasons per Agent in the list, or are you trying to count all "Break" reasons in all agents? The reason I ask is again, you're doing your last `foreach` loop on your iterator variable, after your iteration process has completed.

To count all elements' breaks, do this instead of your second loop:

```
int count = newAgentList.Sum(agent => 
    agent.AuxReasons.Count(reasons => 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reasons) && reasons.StartsWith("Break")));
```

If you want to count the iterator while you're operating on it, use the inner lambda function in your first loop like this:

```
foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
{
    // other logic from above
    int count = newAgents.AuxReasons.Count(r => 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r) && r.StartsWith("Break");
    // do something with count before loop ends
}
```

If you do this latter version, you're going to need to do something with that count before the loop's iteration completes or it will be lost.

If all this is unclear, here's a fully modified version of your code:

```
List<NewAgent> newAgentList = new List<NewAgent>();

foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
{
    NewAgent newAgents = new ScoreBoardClientTest.NewAgent();

    newAgents.AgentName = item.AgName;

    newAgents.AgentExtension = item.Extension;

    newAgents.AgentDateTimeChange = ConvertedDateTimeUpdated;

    newAgents.AuxReasons = item.AuxReasonDescription;

    newAgents.LoginIdentifier = item.LoginId;

    newAgents.AgentState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;

    var timeSpanSince = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;
    newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange = timeSpanSince;

    newAgentList.Add(newAgents);
}

int breakCount = newAgentList.Count(agent => 
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(agent.AuxReasons) && agent.AuxReasons.StartsWith("Break"));
```

Comment: So I tried yours first. char does not contain a definition for StartsWith is the error i'm getting. and cannot convert from char to string.

Comment: I see... `AuxReasons` is a `string`, so you were iterating over each character of it. I've updated my answer to reflect this for posterity, but for future reference please be aware that this is what caused your initial problem.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

first move

```
NewAgent newAgents = new ScoreBoardClientTest.NewAgent();
```

into the first loop so the newAgents will be new when you add it
second , the second foreach is on a string so it gives you list of chars